# Create function in html with angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

Is there a way to create a function in html view. Because I have data and I used ng-repeat to diplay them in my html view. I used ng-if to display the first 15 data in the first table and the second 15 data in the second table and so on... . 
My concern now is I am creating a table three times and I think it's repetitive code. The 3 tables have the same code except I only changed the ng-if condition. I want a shorter code to make it reusable. Is there a way for it? Thanks.

My fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/DharkRoses/kpw43k95/
sample of my code is:

```
 <table border=1>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-if = "$index <= 14">
        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.stat}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Split your data in chunks in your controller. Then use 2 ng-repeat: one outer loop over the chunks which displays each chunk as a table, and one inner loop over the element of the chunk to display the rows of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a directive for that, see https://jsfiddle.net/kpw43k95/1/

here I have created a directive name `uiFoo`, which contains the template for the table,

**Directive:**

```
    app.directive('uiFoo', 
        function() {
          return {
            restrict: 'EAC',

              template:'<td>{{user.id}}</td><td>{{user.name}}</td><td>{{user.stat}}</td>',
            link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {

            }
          };
        }
      );
```

**Html:**

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="check">
        <div class = "container">
        <table border=1>
            <tr ng-repeat="user in users" ui-foo ng-if = "$index <= 14">

            </tr>
        </table>

          <table border=1 class>
            <tr ng-repeat="user in users" ui-foo ng-if = "$index > 14 && $index <=29">

            </tr>
        </table>

             <table border=1>
            <tr ng-repeat="user in users" ui-foo  ng-if = "$index > 29">

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

link the template html in your directive,  and you are done! its reusable.

Comment: Yes you are right. . That way will be more cleaner and more reusable thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirty way :

```
<table border=1 ng-repeat="col in [0,1,2]">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-if = "$index >= col*15 && $index < (col+1)*15">
        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.stat}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ocuznpov/

But it will not adapt to the length of the array if you get over 15*3 items

Comment: wow that is nice answer so short :-). Can you explain to me what is the purpose of this ng-repeat="col in [0,1,2]"?  How the  ng-if = "$index >= col*15 && $index < (col+1)*15" works? @Renan

Comment: First, we repeat the table three times with ng-repeat="col in [0,1,2]".
Then we get the different ranges for ng-if dependin on the col variable : for col=0, col*15 (lower limit) is 0, and (col+1)*15 is 15, so we show items of $index 0..14